# Implementing the __add__ Method in a Counter Class how?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to implement the **add** method in the Counter class. Without importing Counter.

I kinda had an idea as seen in the code but it always gives me an Error.

```
class MyCounter:
    def __init__(self, s=None):
        self.q = {}
        for x in s:
            self.add(x)
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.q)
    def add (self,x):
        if x in self.q:
            self.q[x] = self.q[x] + 1
        else:
            self.q[x]=1
    def __add__(self, args):
        new_dict = self.q
        for x in new_dict:
            if x in args:
                u=args.get(x)
                new_dict[x] = new_dict[x]+ u
            else:
                new_dict[x]=1
```

this is what i want

```
a= MyCounter("hahahahha")
a+ MyCounter("hahhahahah")

new_dict = {'h': 11, 'a': 8}
```

error code if i try it

TypeError: argument of type 'MyCounter' is not iterable

Comment: That's not how you override `__add__`, you might want to take a look at https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh It looks good to me, obvious the `args` parameter name is a bit confusing (as opposed to `other`), but other than that it seems good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line:

```
if x in args:
```

Is essentially:

```
if x in MyCounter("hahhahahah"):
```

But `MyCounter` doesn't support the `in` operator.

You probably wanna check against the `q` instead:

```
if x in args.q:
```

You could also implement the `in` operator for your class (using the `__contains__` method), or subclass from `dict` directly (this is what `collections.Counter` does).

You also have the same issue here:

```
u=args.get(x)
```

`MyCounter` doesn't have `get()` method, you wanna use this instead:

```
u=args.q.get(x)
```

Comment: ye okay that helped me alot. Thanks alot ^-^

Comment: If it solved your problem, you should consider [marking it as the correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)